# Is there a tool to disassemble .NET assemblies into Reflection.Emit code?

Tags: .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm starting to look into dynamically created assemblies using Reflection.Emit, and I'm wondering if there is any tool which can disassembly an existing code into the instructions required to emit it using Reflection.Emit. ildasm / Reflector can give me the IL code for a module and I can use them as a "template" for coding with System.Reflection.Emit classes to "copy" it, but I was wondering if there is any tool which does this extra step of creating the ref.emit instructions to make my learning easier.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Why do you want to copy it instead you can simply write instructions to call it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "translating" the IL code into ref.emit instructions.

Comment: Yes I got that, but if you have the assembly and if you can access it, in your dynamic assembly you can call the method of assembly.

Comment: What I really want is to learn how to use the emit assemblies; what I'd normally do would be to write a small library, build it and then look at the reflection.emit instructions I'd need to do to use it as a template for when I want to write a *similar* library, not to consume that one specifically.

Comment: Well sounds interesting but when .NET offers you dynamic compilation as well, why you would still be interested in reflection.emit? Have you tried dynamic compilation?

Comment: Reflection.Emit is supported on Silverlight, and AFAIK dynamic compilation is not.

Comment: Oh yes, good point, but we do compilation on server side and then ship the dll to silverlight client as dynamic module.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't thought about this. I'll take a look at this option. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin for the [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com): [Reflection.Emit Language](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=reflectionemitlanguage&referringtitle=home&ProjectName=reflectoraddins)

Comment: It seems this plugin is abandoned and it doesn't work with Reflector 8.5+. Do you know any alternative?